# Can't start the laravel-websockets admin page

Tags: laravel, nginx, websocket

I have the demo laravel websockets app up and running on a centos server, having followed the basic installation instructions here:
https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets-demo

I've also got it set up and running in Nginx (so am not running php artisan serve)

However, I can't get the `php artisan websockets:serve` command to work. on the cli it says:

> "Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001..."

And I can get into `mydomain/laravel-websockets` and see the admin console, but it can't connect - instead I get a

> "Channels current state is unavailable"
>   error.

If I do the exact same steps on my local machine, without going through Nginx, the websocket connecting works fine.

I can't find any reference to the laravel-websockets package error logging or where I might find it.. there are no errors being logged in `app/storage/logs`.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Any luck getting this to work? I am having the same problem

Comment: yes see the answer I posted. you need to open port 6001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be that I needed to open port 6001 in the EC2 console.

[image: open outbound ports]

Once I did this I could see:

> Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...
>   New connection opened for app key someKey.
>   Connection id 531095113.417906678 sending message {"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{\"socket_id\":\"531095113.417906678\",\"activity_timeout\":30}"}
>   someKey: connection id 531095113.417906678 received message: {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"someKey:6ed67f163e2eee2460fb0fbc8ce33f7b6a8e4080a535d4a101bbe9b15a1b29d6","channel":"private-websockets-dashboard-subscribed"}}.

And the laravel websockets dashboard could connect.

So Simple (when you know!)

Comment: Good lookin out. sudo ufw allow 6001/tcp