# React native custom host pusher connection

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pusher, pusher-js

[image: pusher log]
Can't seem to connect to pusher. I've been working in these for days and can't seem to connect to pusher. version 6.0.3

```
 import Pusher from 'pusher-js/react-native';

componentDidMount() {
    this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
        'willFocus',
        () => {

            try {
                this.pusher = new Pusher('key', {
                    wsHost: 'host',
                    wsPort: 6001,
                    enabledTransports: ['ws'],
                    disableStats:true,
                });
                Pusher.log = (msg) => {
                    console.log('Pusher message ' + msg);
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error', error)
            }

            this.group_channel = this.pusher.subscribe('groupchat.' + session_id);
            this.pusher.connection.bind('GroupMessageSent', (data) => {
                console.log('connected', data)
            });
            this.group_channel.bind('GroupMessageSent', (data) => {
                console.log('data', data)
            });


        })
}
```

Pusher message Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"xhr_polling","url":"https://sockjs-4444.pusher.com:443/pusher/app/DOCKOTO_KEY?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.3"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://snack.expo.io/@jsfit/pusher

I have checked the pusher is working fine for me on the localhost
the main reason I think is your ws `ws://test.dockoto.com:6001`
Laravel WebSockets default port `6001` as you know but you still need to open the port on the server.

***Shared hosting*** I think you have to contact with you hosting provider to open the port if needed

***EC2:*** 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56667321/13647574

Comment: You mean. you connected to ws://test.dockoto.com:6001 in your localhost?

Comment: No my own pusher setup

Comment: this is all I need to setup pusher right? just making sure that I did not forgot any setup.